# Vue output is `[object Module]` for my embedded SVG

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, webpack

I'm trying to embed SVGs for my Vue component and have been struggling with the following code for a few days now.

A large part came from https://calebporzio.com/using-inline-svgs-in-vue-compoments. Would appreciate it if someone could point out why I keep getting `[object Module]` in the HTML output instead of the desired SVG.

I'm not using mix, just webpack. I believe all code related to the issue has been shared, can show others required.

Thank you.

My `package.json`

```
...
"devDependencies":{
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    ....
}
```

```
<!-- components/SvgIcon.vue -->
<template>
    <div v-html="require(`!html-loader!@svg/${icon}.svg`)"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['icon']
}
</script>
```

```
<!-- components/button.vue -->
<template>
    ...
    <svg-icon icon="myicon"></svg-icon> <!-- this shows up as [object Module] in the final HTML output -->
    ...
</template>
<script>
import SvgIcon from './SvgIcon.vue';
Vue.component('svg-icon', SvgIcon)
...
<script>
```

```
<!-- svg/myicon.svg -->
<svg........
```

```js
// webpack.config.js
const { dirname } = require("path");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@svg": path.resolve(__dirname, "svg"),
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: I take it this is the old vuejs, i.e. version 2

Comment: correct, vue v2

Comment: it's interesting that in the link you provided, when that person used `!html-loader!` there was apparently *much display* ...and indeed, in the *Finishing the component* section, there is no `!html-loader!` present ...

Comment: I tried with and without.. both led to `[object module]`, it seems they added some config to tell `mix` (which i'm not using) to use html-loader instead of the usual loader, unfortunately, that was beyond my very limited knowledge of webpack/mix/vue.